# Laravel 5.5 - Check if only one column will be updated

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 5.5 and models, I would like to know, before updated if only one column, statut, will be updated.

The interest is to just updated the statut if there are no changes or, if there are  some columns to be updated, create a new row. Because each modification need to be approved before published.

Actually, I have a big if like :

```
if($request->statut != $product->statut && $request->title == $product ...)
```

Is there a quickest way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have at the minute?

Comment: you might be interested with this: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getDirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `isDirty('field')` method to check if the field was changed (and not yet saved). `getDirty()` will return you array of all such fields and their values.

If I understood your case correctly, then you can do:

```php
if ($product->isDirty('statut')) {
    if (count($product->getDirty()) == 1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

First we check if field `statut` was changed for your `$product`. Then we just check if number of changed fields is 1 (meaning that there are no more changed fields than just `statut`).

Comment: Thanks ! I believed that dirty method was called after use save().  So perfect, have a nice day.